# Xamarin UI menu and navigation between views

Tags: c#, ios, uinavigationcontroller, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to build my first iOS app with Xamarin, and I'm using [this project](https://github.com/thedillonb/MonoTouch.SlideoutNavigation) to to add a facebook style menu to the left, but I am having some problems getting it to display.

I load the menu and my first view controller in the app delegate like this:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
        Menu = new SlideoutNavigationController();
        Menu.SlideHeight = 9999f;
        Menu.TopView = new InitialController();
        Menu.MenuViewLeft = new DummyControllerLeft();
        Menu.LeftMenuButtonText = "Menu";

        window.RootViewController = Menu;
        window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

        return true;
    }
```

This works fine, and the page is loaded with the menu in place, and if I use the menu to navigate then all works as expected. The problem is that I have navigation that takes place from other input, such as a button press on the main page, rather than via the menu. When this occurs it loads the right page, put the menu button is no longer present, I can drag from the left to bring the menu in, but the button is missing. I'm using something like this to move to this page, this code is in teh ViewDidLoad fucntion of the InitialController class (the one used as the top view in the menu)

```
NavigationController.PushViewController(new OnlineMembersViewController(false), true);
```

I'm very new to this so I imagine I am doing something silly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should manually add that button. If you look through sources of that `SlideoutNavigationController` you will see that it adds the menu button only for that view controllers that you navigating through side menu. So you should manually set `View.NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItem` or `View.NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItem` and add on touch event call the `ShowMenuRight/ShowMenuLeft` for other view controllers

```
private void SomeEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((AppDelegate)UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate).Menu.ShowMenuRight(); 
    //or
    //((AppDelegate)UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate).Menu.ShowMenuLeft(); 
}
```